# Apostrophe CMS: Do we have middleware/hook which can set global.data from API?

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms

My requiment is I have an API which will provide user data. In the Apostrophe CMS I need to access the user data from all the layouts (Header, Main, Footer).

I can see gobal.data which is avaiable everywhere in the template. Likewise I need a hook which will call the API and store the response data in the Apostrophe's global.data.

Please let me know if you need further informations.

Answer (score 0):

You could hit that API on every page render:

```
// index.js of some apostrophe module

// You should `npm install request-promise` first
const request = require('request-promise');

module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.on('apostrophe-pages:beforeSend', async function(req) {
      const apiInfo = await request('http://some-api.com/something');
      req.data.apiInfo = apiInfo;
      // now in your templates you can access `data.apiInfo`
    });
  }
}
```

But this will hit that API on every single request which will of course make your site slow down. So I would recommend that you cache the information for some period of time.